deleting disks also removed the instant snapshots in GCP
I deleted few disks but then their instant snapshots are also gone, there is not trace of the snapshots in GCP console.
the documentation clearly mentions that disk delete wont delete the snapshots. any way to recover from this.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/delete

In GCP Instant snapshots are different from regular snapshots. As mentioned in the document, deleting the disk does not delete the snapshots. But it only applies to the standard snapshots. Instant snapshots need to be deleted before deleting the disk. Refer to this troubleshooting instant disk deletion document.
As per the official GCP document limitation (last bulletin point):

"You can't recover deleted instant snapshots. "

Therefore the instant snapshots you were having might have been deleted while deleting the disks.
If you want to recover the data you have to reach Google Cloud Support and they might help you to recover the deleted disks.

exactly, i didnt delete the snapshots but still they are missing
